# Error when generating JNI header file

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to generate the JNI header file through command line. when I 
typed javah myclass.class, the errors was

```
Exception in thread main java.IllegalArgumentException: not a valid class name
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask<JavacTool.java:177>
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask<JavacTool.java:68>
at com.sun.tools.javah.api.JavachTask.run<JavahTask.java:509>
at com.sun.tools.javah.api.JavachTask.run<JavahTask.java:335>
at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main<Main.java:46>
```

but when I typed javah myclass

Error:could not find class file for 'myclass'

Previously, when  I typed ls in the my class directory, the class file was exist.

this is my snippet codes

```
package com.blablabla

public static native long myclass(long n);
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

thanks

Comment: You're not 'extracting the header from the native code'. You are *generating* the header from the *compiled Java code.* The header isn't in there to be 'extracted'.

Answer (score 2):

May be you should try giving fully qualified class name: -

```
javah com.blablabla.myclass
```

Comment: And also @deduu might need to specify the classpath from which to load classes.

Comment: do you mean "javah -classpath bin/classes/com.example.FibLib -d /jni" ? it produces error: no class specified

Answer (score 1):

The class name starts with a lowercase character, try using uppercase, as is the mandated convention in Java. Additionally, try specifying the fully-qualified name (listing all the packages separated by `.`)

Comment: Hi Oscar, I'm sorry for my inconsistentcy. actually the class file is FibLib.class. I've try specified the fully-qualified name, and it works. thanks to you. by the way,next I wanna create .dll file. do you know how to create .dll file from cmd by using keyword "cl"? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the .class part of the argument. The argument is the fully qualified *class name,* not a file name. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the fully qualified class names is a huge pain. You might take a look at the [set of scripts I wrote to deal with this headache](https://github.com/joshbooks/jniUtil) or just [the script that deals with this particular problem](https://github.com/joshbooks/jniUtil/blob/master/genJniHeaders.sh) if you want to write your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the cmd window (Windows, obviously), and from the folder containing javah.exe, I typed

```
javah -classpath C:\my\project\path\PackageDirectory\packagename\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug com.company.package.MyKotlinClass
```

The file MyKotlinClass.class was in the folder

```
C:\my\project\path\PackageDirectory\packagename\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\com\company\package\
```

Note, I used a mixture of specifying the class path and qualifying the class name.